# MAMP doesnt work with Yosemite after the Patch

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, osx-yosemite, mamp-pro

Tried the below

> Workaround for the 10.10 Preview 5 bug: Rename the file “envvars”
>   located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into “_envvars”

Patched by renaming
[image]

Quit MAMP and restarted still am getting the following error

[image]

When i got to `http://localhost/` I get a page that says

> It works!

But when i go to the folders that used to work before i get an error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /prayag/ was not found on this server.
```

When i try to visit MySQL also i get the following error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have removed or otherwise disabled the native Apache server on OSX, it will start automatically and your Servers associated with your MAMP installation won't start.

To see if this is the problem, try opening a Terminal and issue the command:

sudo apachectl stop

Then try starting your MAMP servers again.

Comment: will starting the native apache will it affect anything else in my OS? i mean is anything OS related using apache?

Comment: It'll have no effect on the rest of the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to kill all sql service and restart:

Steps:

1. Quit MAMP
2. Open the terminal and type: killall -9 mysqld
3. Restart MAMP